# ItemSend event is not firing

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook 2007 Add-in (VSTO). Any mail sent with Outlook should be modified before that.

I use the `Application.ItemSend` event and it works fine if I send an email directly from Outlook (`Inspector`) or through a 
custom C# application that uses the `Send` method of the `MailItem`.

However, there is some external application that uses Outlook to send mails - which does not trigger the `ItemSend` event at all. The mail is moved directly to the Outbox (*I can even catch the event of `ItemAdd` on that folder*) and then sent.

Another interesting issue is that if I define a **deferred delivery rule** it works OK if I send a mail with the `Inspector` or my c# code, but not when this application does it.

My question is when and how can you create a message that passes the `ItemSend` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design: messages created and sent by Simple MAPI or mailto url do not trigger OOM events. This is done on purpose - there were some problems in those scenarios, so events were completely disabled.