# Run Outlook Macro when sending mail from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a VBA code in Thisoutlooksession that runs when new mail is sent.
But when I send a mail using Excel biltin option to send the file attached, the code in the outlook don't run.
Would appreciate youre help.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a situation where some Outlook functionality is not applied.

"You use Send As or other Send commands from another Microsoft Office application, such as Microsoft Word, Microsoft Excel, or Microsoft PowerPoint. This scenario typically occurs when you use a command to send the current file as an attachment." [Messages that are created outside Outlook do not include the default Outlook email signature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2544665/messages-that-are-created-outside-outlook-do-not-include-the-default-o)

"If you need all features to be available, you either need to create the email from Outlook itself or create the new email programmatically from within that other application as well." [Outlook UserForms dont work when emailing from another application](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/outlook-userforms-dont-work-when-emailing-from/5f7e29f5-4007-44e1-822c-8f0c9a8aae09)

"This is by design: messages created and sent by Simple MAPI or mailto url do not trigger OOM events. This is done on purpose - there were some problems in those scenarios, so events were completely disabled." [ItemSend event is not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177345/itemsend-event-is-not-firing)